# Assign specific IP to application

Tags: debian, networking, ip

Here is my current setup:

- *Machine A* with a single *ipA*: general purpose debian server with ssh, web server, etc...
- *Machine B* with a single *ipB*: openvpn server (also on debian)

My aim is to use the same physical machine to do the same (*Machine C* with both *ipA* and *ipB* on the same physical interface) :

- everything (ssh, web server, ...) through *ipA*
- except openvpn through *ipB*.

My requirement is that an external user should not be able (excluding side-channels) to infer that ipA and ipB route to the same physical machine.
As an example, all current services of Machine A should not listen on ipB.

Moreover, since Machine B is only used for openvpn, I would like to avoid a hypervisor-based solution. I hope there is a way to "jail" openvpn and ipB under my existing OS.

**Which technology/packages should I use in this case?**

Since openvpn is latency sensitive and resources hungry, light technologies are preferred.

Comment: Examples: in your openvpn config, use `local w.x.y.z` to specify which IP address to listen on.  In your sshd config use the `ListenAddress` directive.  ...

Comment: @user4556274 :  Adding specific config lines to openvpn to use ipB is fine. Adding specific config lines to **every** other service to use ipA is horrible.

Comment: Configure each service, or setup a local firewall, or (however I am not sure about this) maybe containers.

Comment: @richard Yes, network namespace isolation (or containers) is the way to go IMHO for this kind of issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best choice is to do that in every service configuration and set every service to listen for specific ip not any ip, but, you can do that in `iptables` so you can drop any packet that have destination ipB and the port is not `openvpn` port or only allow destination ipB and port `openvpn` but you here you will lose the ability to use the port with ipA.

For exmpale:

```
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p udp -d <ipB> --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp -d <ipB> --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT

iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p udp --dport 1194 -j DROP
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 1194 -j DROP
```

Here am only allowing the connection on port `1194` for the packet that have destination ipB

Comment: I would agree that a firewall solution would be best, that way you keep it all in one place. However I would look for a nice tool to edit iptables for you. I use gufw, but don't like it, as there is no way to add comments, of named variables, or anything else to make the configuration readable.

Comment: @richard i don't think that firewall solution is the best here.
and you are right there are no way to add variables, but you can add comments to `iptables` file then restore the rules from it, and when you want to edit or to read go back to the file and don't read it directly

Comment: Why not a firewall? And your solution is a firewall.

Comment: I said that best choice is to do configuration for every service, the firewall well not allow you to use the same port for both ips for deferent service, because the system will say the port is already in use

Comment: Ah I see, we can not use firewall alone to allow port m on IPa and port m on IPb. However I would use the firewall in addition, as an assurance. But, yes, better to configure each one separately. I wonder if containers can be used to ease this.

Comment: @richard container will do the job if they have a public ips, and i think it's the best choice

Comment: What is public ips?

Comment: @richard i meant routable ips

Comment: But what is ips? Is it IP address. If so then what difference does it make, can you explain. Do you mean one with ipA and one with ipB (ip address names from quesion)?

Comment: @richard sry, ips mean IPs, i was talking in general case, in this case ipA and ipB can need to be assigned to two containers, and the host have its own IP, and you can't use one ip for the host then use local IPs for containers so in this case we back to that you can't run two containers that have the save port for deferent services

Comment: I have been messing with docker ( a containerisation tool), over the last few days. It allows you to have one service per container, it uses union (layered) file-system to allow containers to share part(often most) of there image. The containers don't have there own IP address (at least not the ones I was messing with), you configure a mapping between internal ports and a host ip:port. All of the configuration is in one place (container deployment).